Did Philo ever mention crucifixion as a punishment in any of his writings? If he didn't, was there ever a reason he didn't?
Philo was a prominent Roman writer and philosopher during the first century AD, it seems that in one of his books 'Against Flaccus' Philo mentions the multiple persecutions and punishments Jews of that time were facing, but it seems that the crucifixion wasn't mentioned?
I have some ideas why this would be, but I am not sure. Is it possibly because crucifixion was so commonplace that there was no need to mention it or was it the fact that Alexandria just didn't use this method of punishment? I think it is the latter because there is no historical evidences of crucifixion in Alexandria but I maybe wrong.
Because it is historically accepted citation needed that this was one of the most commonly used form of punishment in the Roman Empire starting from the BC period, there is historical evidencecitation needed  in mainland Rome and it is accepted that they had brought this form of punishment everywhere they went.
Again, I have a question because I have read somewhere citation needed that Philo would go back to Jerusalem from time to time and it is historically established that crucifixion was taking place under Pontius Pilate and his successor during Philo's life time.

Is there some reason you think that crucifixion was used specifically to persecute Jews?

@cmw No, I think everyone regardless of origin was being persecuted but Philo is Jew and he was specifically focused on Jewish affairs.

Sorry, the emphasis in my question is on the word persecution. Why would we expect crucifixion to be used here?

Because it is historically accepted that this was one of the most commonly used form of punishment in the Roman Empire starting from the BC period, there is historical evidence in mainland Rome and it is accepted that they had brought this form of punishment everywhere they went.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)

@Howwhye - every comment makes it harder to understand the question, which decreases the probability and quality of the answer. Recommend you edit the question to address the comment, then flag the comment for deletion.

You also might want to note the difference between punishment and persecution. Philo isn't talking about law courts. It can be helpful to read Philo directly on the topic, which should clarify what's going on persecution-wise. Here's a link to Philo's text. Start at IX to get a sense of how Flaccus went about the persecutions.

The vast majority of Philo's writings were concerned with Philosophical and Religious matters (which many people at the time did not consider as completely separate things). However he had one writing I found that dealt with contemporaneous history/politics.
Against Flaccus was intended as a catalog of the cruelty and incompetence of the Roman governor of Egypt. Contrary to the "I have heard" claim in the question, it explicitly mentions crucifixions.

I have known instances before now of men who had been crucified when
this festival and holiday was at hand, being taken down and given up
to their relations, in order to receive the honours of sepulture, and
to enjoy such observances as are due to the dead; for it used to be
considered, that even the dead ought to derive some enjoyment from the
natal festival of a good emperor, and also that the sacred character
of the festival ought to be regarded.
But this man did not order
men who had already perished on crosses to be taken down, but he
commanded living men to be crucified, men to whom the very time itself
gave, if not entire forgiveness, still, at all events, a brief and
temporary respite from punishment; and he did this after they had been
beaten by scourgings in the middle of the theatre; and after he had
tortured them with fire and sword;
and the spectacle of their
sufferings was divided; for the first part of the exhibition lasted
from the morning to the third or fourth hour, in which the Jews were
scourged, were hung up, were tortured on the wheel, were condemned,
and were dragged to execution through the middle of the orchestra; and
after this beautiful exhibition came the dancers, and the buffoons,
and the flute-players, and all the other diversions of the theatrical
contests.

